# Bootstrap slide animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to scroll the div by animation but , it is not working. There might be some point where I was doing mistake but don't know what. Please help if anyone can fix this.
I was trying to follow this http://codepen.io/jmgiorgi_/pres/cLyCk

html code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <TITLE>
        Demo
    </TITLE>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_Bootstrap.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/customFunctions.js"></script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<div id="wrapper" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#spy" class="">


<div class="wrapper">
        <!--Sidebar View-->
        <div class=" visible-sm visible-md visible-lg col-md-2 col-sm-4 sidebar1 ">
            <!--<div class="  affix">-->
                <div class="logo">

                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-64-64-1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Logo">

                    <br>
                    <!-- <nav role='navigation'> -->
                    <!-- <div class="well sidebar1"> -->
                    <ul class="list  ">
                        <!-- <ul class="list"> -->
                        <!-- <h5><strong>WHEREABOUTS</strong></h5> -->
                        <li><a   href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a   href="#education">Education</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#achievements">Achievements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#extra">Extra Curriculum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                    <!-- </nav> -->
                <!--</div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


        <!--Main content-->

        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 main-content">
            <!--Main content code to be written here -->

            <section  class="row"   name ="home" id="home">
                <span> Demo</span>
                <h2>DEmo App</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>


                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </section>

            <section class="row" name ="education" id="education">
                <span> Second Part</span>

                <h2>karane</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>


                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>


                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>



                <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>



                <h1>FEEDBACK APPRECIATED! :)</h1>
                <h3>P.S.: For side navbar with dropdown menu, you may refer this snippet: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/kWPoW</h3>
            </section>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</div>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

custom_Bootstrap.css file

```
.sidebar1 {
    background: #F17153;
    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F17153, #F58D63, #f1ab53);
    /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#F17153, #F58D63, #f1ab53);
    /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F17153, #F58D63, #f1ab53);
    /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#F17153, #F58D63, #f1ab53);
    /* Standard syntax */
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;

    height:100%;

    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed!important;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:auto
}

.hidden{
    opacity:0;
}
.visible{
    opacity:1;
}

#wrapper {

    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}


.logo {
    max-height: 130px;
}
.logo>img {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.list {
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.list::first-line {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.list> li, h5 {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 40px;
}
.list>li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-left: 5px solid white;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-left: 35px;
}.main-content{
     text-align:center;
 }

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
    .sidebar1.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

customFunctions.js file

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
        // On-page links
        if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
            &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
            // Figure out element to scroll to
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            // Does a scroll target exist?
            if (target.length) {
                // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000, function() {
                    // Callback after animation
                    // Must change focus!
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $target.focus();
                    if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats wrong? it is working

Comment: it is working but I want it when press on option , it slowly goes to that page not immediately like smooth -slide

Comment: You aren't using a doctype, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code already works great. If you want it to slide slower adjust `animate seconds` in your `customFunction.js`

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
// Remove links that don't actually link to anything
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
        // On-page links
        if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
            &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
            // Figure out element to scroll to
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            // Does a scroll target exist?
            if (target.length) {
                // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 3000, function() {
                    // Callback after animation
                    // Must change focus!
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $target.focus();
                    if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I changed it from `1000` to `3000`. It looks laggy but for me your current `1000` works better.

Comment: This is not gonna work , error with some architecture not speed.

Comment: What do you mean it will not work? can you please give more details about the issue. Your code above works, and you said in the comment you want it to scroll slowly, that is how it suppose to slow down base on your code.

Comment: I have mentioned the codepen.io link above. Code is scroll to that content but not smooth scrolling

Comment: The codepen link works the same thing as the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add an click event to elements which aren't in the DOM jet.
You have to wrap it inside a $(document).ready() or move the script to end of body (before the </body>-tag)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $anchor = $('a[href*="#"]');
    console.log("anchor size:", $anchor.length);
    $anchor
        // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
        .not('[href="#"]')
        .not('[href="#0"]')
        .click(function(event) {
            // On-page links
            if (
                location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
                &&
                location.hostname == this.hostname
            ) {
                // Figure out element to scroll to
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                // Does a scroll target exist?
                console.log("target size:", target.length);
                if (target.length) {
                    // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000, function() {
                        // Callback after animation
                        // Must change focus!
                        var $target = $(target);
                        $target.focus();
                        if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                        };
                    });
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I've edited the code. can please use it, and in case it doesn't work please share the console output (after a click)

Comment: its not working, How can I share console output, well you use it in plunkr

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that jQuery 3 removes the size-Function. if i replace "$anchor.size()" with "$anchor.length" it works @ plunker. And the console output you get from your browser dev tool, to open it press F12 (in most cases, if not please use google to find it for your browser)